# Is whole date better than separate parts of the date in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following two tables. table2 contains date in a single column whereas table1 takes two column to represent the date, so is table2 better than table1?

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
select 2017 as year, "January" as month
)

or

#standardSQL
with table2 as(
select "01/15/2017" as date
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most practical cases I would recommend what you see in Table2
Or even better to store it not as a string but rather a a date data type
In any case  - string or date - here are plenty of respective functions that support your potential needs in manipulating dates